# Some ways to sort a collection of comparables in eiffel

Tags: collections, comparable, eiffel

Which library of the kernel should I use to sort a collection in eiffel?

where can I find an example of sort? are the tipical bubble sort, etc available?

Any sorter with agent would be very useful too to avoid having to do it with a comparable which is not implemented for example with PATH class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library `base_extension` provides a deferred class [`SORTER`](https://www.eiffel.org/files/doc/static/trunk/libraries/base_extension/sorter_chart.html) with effective [implementations](https://www.eiffel.org/files/doc/static/trunk/libraries/base_extension/sorter_links.html) of bubble, quick and shell sort algorithms.

It uses a comparator object to do the comparison on elements of an arbitrary type, not necessarily of type `COMPARABLE`. One of implementations of the comparator interface is `AGENT_EQUALITY_TESTER` to which you pass an agent to determine whether one object is less than another one.

Here is an example how paths can be sorted by their canonical name using bubble sort:

```
sort_paths (a_paths: INDEXABLE [PATH, INTEGER])
    local
        l_sorter: SORTER [PATH]
    do
        create {BUBBLE_SORTER [PATH]} l_sorter.make
            (create {AGENT_EQUALITY_TESTER [PATH]}.make (
                agent (a_p1, a_p2: PATH): BOOLEAN
                    do
                        Result := a_p1.canonical_path < a_p2.canonical_path
                    end))
        l_sorter.sort (a_paths)
    end
```

Now, if there is a list of paths `paths` of type `ARRAYED_LIST [PATH]`, it can be sorted by calling `sort_paths (paths)`.

Comment: It works, many thx, may I ask you how an `ARRAYED_LIST[PATH]` conforms to `INDEXABLE[PATH, INTEGER]` I missed this part

Comment: @Pipo Here is the inheritance path: `ARRAYED_LIST` -> `DYNAMIC_LIST` -> `LIST` -> `CHAIN` -> `INDEXABLE`. `CHAIN` represents a sequence of items, therefore it's indexable. You can change the signature of `sort_paths` to accept `ARRAYED_LIST [PATH]` instead of `INDEXABLE`. I just used the most general type.

Comment: With the general signature you can also sort `ARRAY [PATH]` or `TWO_WAY_LIST [PATH]` (though in the latter case the efficiency would be problematic, as the sorters rely on the possibility to read and write elements at "random" positions, so it's better to pass structure with efficient access by an index).

Comment: thx, my question was more about PATH, INTEGER where is the second generic parameter given for conformance? I think I'd have to search into descendants of PATH...

Comment: @Pipo `INTEGER` is the type of the index to access items. My guess is that it is there for historical reasons.

Comment: PATH is a heir of INDEXABLE[PATH, INTEGER], that was the answer of my conformity question

Comment: @Pipo No, the essential fact here is that `ARRAYED_LIST [PATH]` conforms to `INDEXABLE [PATH, INTEGER]`.